# export powershell result into sql database

Tags: sql-server-2008, powershell

Im am new to powershell and currenly working out on a code to export powershell result into a specific database for example ITAMMVCDB.mdf and table name Hardware.

ive created this database(SQL Server 2008) with the table (assuming all attribute is type varchar(5000))and trying to export a powershell script result into this database.

```
[cmdletbinding()]
param (
 [parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    [string[]]$ComputerName = $env:computername
)            

begin {}
process {
 foreach ($Computer in $ComputerName) {
  if(Test-Connection -ComputerName $Computer -Count 1 -ea 0) {
   $Networks = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -ComputerName $Computer | ? {$_.IPEnabled}
   $OsName = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName  $Computer | Select Name, Version
   $Memory = Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem  -ComputerName  $Computer | Select  TotalPhysicalMemory, Manufacturer, Model , Domain
   $Disk = Get-WMIObject Win32_LogicalDisk  -ComputerName   $Computer  | Select DeviceID,Size  
   $Serial = Get-WMIObject Win32_SystemEnclosure  -ComputerName   $Computer  | Select SerialNumber
   $Processor = Get-WMIObject Win32_Processor  -ComputerName   $Computer  | Select Name
   $Serial = Get-WMIObject Win32_SystemEnclosure  -ComputerName   $Computer  | Select SerialNumber

   foreach ($Network in $Networks) {
    $IPAddress  = $Network.IpAddress[0]

    $os = $OsName.Name 
    $Version=$OsName.Version
    $mem= $memory.TotalPhysicalMemory
    $Manufacturer= $memory.Manufacturer
    $Model= $memory.Model
    $Domain = $Memory.Domain
    $DiskSize = $Disk.Size
    $SerialNo = $Serial.SerialNumber
    $ProcessorSpeed = $Processor.Name
    $SerialNo = $Serial.SerialNumber

    $OutputObj  = New-Object -Type PSObject
    $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name ComputerName -Value $Computer.ToUpper()
    $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name IPAddress -Value $IPAddress

    $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Name -Value $os
    $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Version -Value $Version
    $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name TotalPhysicalMemory -Value $mem
    $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Manufacturer -Value $Manufacturer
    $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Model -Value $Model
    $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name DiskSize -Value $Disk
    $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Processor -Value $ProcessorSpeed
    $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name SerialNumber -Value $SerialNo
    $OutputObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Domain -Value $Domain
    $OutputObj | Export-CSV -Path “C:\y3s1\report.csv”
   }
  }
 }
}            

end {}
```

i managed to export it to a csv file and works fine. how should i modify the code above to export the result to "ITAMMVCDB.mdf" database and in table named "Hardware"

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the sqlcmd.exe command-line utility which is included with SQL Server 2005 and higher with a simple T-SQL BULK INSERT command:

```
$query = @"
BULK INSERT [ITAMMVCDB.mdf].[dbo].[Hardware] FROM 'C:\y3s1\report.csv' WITH (FIRSTROW = 2, FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')
"@
sqlcmd -S "yourSQLServer" -E -Q $query
```

Comment: thank you for the solution. it works perfectly when i run as query in sql studio mgmt. how do i run it in powershell? it didnt work when i use $query. am i missing some components?

Comment: I did a test and created a ITAMMVCDB.mdf database and Hardware table and it worked fine for me except that I need to add -NoTypeInformation to CSV creation. What error are you getting.